# Is it possible to add environment variables via appassembler plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, appassembler

Is it possible somehow possible to add a environment variable to the generated scripts say `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BASEDIR/native/libs/`. I did not find anything in the docs. Maybe there will at least be a "hacky" way using another maven plugin?

Comment: What kind of things are you creating JSW, Daemon ?

Comment: Currently just simple script but should become a demon in the end

Comment: Have you taken a look here: http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/generate-daemons-mojo.html#environmentSetupFileName

Comment: @khmarbaise thx, that worked! Dou you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution for this is to use a [environment setup file](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/generate-daemons-mojo.html#environmentSetupFileName) which can be configurate in Appassembler within the pom.xml